# foreach loop count function total

Tags: laravel, foreach

I would like to make a total `count` on my `variable` : `$nb_quota_lic_simples`

In the `foreach` i check how many free licences i have, i would like to get the total of the licences if there is many equipes. Hope someone help me. Thanks a lot in advance !

Actually i have :

```
foreach ($equipes as $equipe) {
    $nb_quota_lic_simples = $equipe->catg_equipe->nb_licences;               
}
dd($nb_quota_lic_simples);
```

Comment: Just use `dd(count($nb_quota_lic_simples));`!

Comment: thnaks for your reply when i do dd($nb_quota_lic_simples); i get 30 and when i do dd(count($nb_quota_lic_simples)) i get = 1 ! i should get 60 . why ?

Comment: Just do $nb_quota_lic_simples += $equipe->catg_equipe->nb_licences;

Comment: i get Undefined variable 'nb_quota_lic_simples' when i do  $nb_quota_lic_simples += $equipe->catg_equipe->nb_licences inside the foreach

Comment: `dd(count($nb_quota_lic_simples))` gives you total number of result of `$nb_quota_lic_simples`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try something like this

```
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($equipes as $equipe) {
        $total += $equipe->catg_equipe->nb_licences;               
    }
    dd($total);
```

Comment: i will accept the answer in 5 min when i can click on it !